# Reference for built-in JavaScript types in node or v8

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, introspection

I'm writing some code that will do some introspection on a `Function` in node. Specifically, I want to hopefully do non-standard-JS things like listing source code line numbers. However, there appears to be no reference documentation available on global types in node/v8 to see what's available.

The [Global Objects documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html) for node doesn't have this information. Although [MDN documents Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function), it only lists *standard* methods/properties or its own non-standard extensions. Also, its compatibility chart focuses on browser JS engines. It helped me find the `name` property of a function at least.

The REPL isn't helping me either:

```
> function foo() { }
undefined
> foo
[Function: foo]
> console.dir(foo)
[Function: foo]
undefined
> Object.keys(foo)
[]
> Object.keys(Function.prototype)
[]
>
```

Is there any sort of reference documentation for global node types?

Comment: What do you mean, "global node types"? Do you expect there to be any non-standard methods?

Comment: Tip: Use `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` instead of `keys`

Comment: Are you planning to write some native code or how do you think introspection will be possible?

Comment: I hoped there was a non-standard method available, but as `getOwnPropertyNames` shows, I'm SOL. Oh well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function allProps(obj, name = '') {
     if (obj == null) return; // recursion to the final link in this prototype chain
     console.log(name, Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj));
     allProps(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj), 'prototype');
}

allProps(Function, 'Function');
allProps(Function.prototype, 'Function.prototype');
allProps(Function.__proto__, 'Function.__proto__');
```